# Integrate via AJAX mailchimp API 3.0 Bootstrap/HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to implement this solution in a similar way using ajax but I get **"bool:false"** as result in `var_dump`.

Is there any error in the code? I've been working for hours but maybe I'm missing something. Please some help would be great!

**Subscribe form:**

```
<form action="scripts/subscribe.php" method="post" id="subscribe_form" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="subscribe_email" placeholder="¿Cuál es tu correo electrónico?">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" id="subscribe_submit" data-loading-text="•••"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Custom JS**

```
$('#subscribe_form').submit(function() {
    $('.error').hide();
    $('.error').fadeIn();
    // submit the form
    if($(this).valid()){
        $('#subscribe_submit').button('loading'); 
        var action = $(this).attr('action');
        $.ajax({
            url: action,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                newsletter_email: $('#subscribe_email').val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#subscribe_submit').button('reset');

                //Use modal popups to display messages
                $('#modalMessage .modal-title').html('<i class="icon icon-envelope-open"></i>' + data);
                $('#modalMessage').modal('show');

            },
            error: function() {
                $('#subscribe_submit').button('reset');

                //Use modal popups to display messages
                $('#modalMessage .modal-title').html('<i class="icon icon-ban"></i>Oops!<br>Something went wrong!');
                $('#modalMessage').modal('show');

            }
        });
    }
    return false; 
});
```

**Mailchimp script:**

```
$apikey = '<Apikey>';
$auth = base64_encode( 'user:'.$apikey );
$email = $_POST['newsletter_email'];

$data = array(
    'apikey'        => $apikey,
    'email_address' => $email,
    'status'        => 'pending'
);
$json_data = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<ListID>/members/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
                                            'Authorization: Basic '.$auth));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);                                                                                                                  

$result = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($result);
die('Mailchimp executed');
```